# htaccess with wordpress inside subdirectory

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

i've a simple question but i cant find and answer for that:

i have in my site-root folder 3 subdirectory, in the first one i have a wordpress site, in the second and in the third two other sites but only for testing like this:

```
domain.com/wordpress/  
domain.com/test1/  
domain.com/test2/
```

Now i want when the user goes on the site to redirect him on my wordpress site but also when i want to access the other sites i directly put the correct address and go. 
Right now i have the code down below but, when i try to connect to other folder he redirect me to the 404 wordpress page. How should i edit it to make it works?

I also want if its possible when i go on wordpress to not show the subdirectory in the url but only the domain:

NOT -> domain.com/wordpress/index.php

BUT -> domain.com/index.php

```
RewriteEngine On #created by aruba do not touch this file!

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)wordpress
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ wordpress/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Who is "aruba"?

Comment: aruba is my domain host